# Camera2 API doesn't work on emualtor

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-camera

I'm trying to work with Camera2 API on emulator but unfortunately i encountered a problem while implementing it.

I'm using the **Camera2Basic** provided by google from this [link](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic) and i tried it on real device and it works fine.

**Real devices are :** Huawei P9 Lite API 24 , Samsung Galaxy S5 API 23.

**Genymotion Emulators are :** Google Nexus 4,5,6 API 21,22,24 , Samsung Galaxy S6,S7 API 23,25

The problem now is when launching the App on emulator it shows the camera (i'm working with a webcam) but when i click on the button picture normally it shows on a toast that the picture is saved in a certain path. But it doesn't , that means that the picture wasn't taken , it only do that on real devices.

I've noticed while building the project the logcat shows this :

```
07-04 07:56:06.252 1694-1694/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No 
such file or directory)
07-04 07:56:06.252 1694-1694/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack 
module: -2
07-04 07:56:07.360 1709-1709/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No 
such file or directory)
07-04 07:56:07.360 1709-1709/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack 
module: -2
07-04 07:56:34.492 1723-1723/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No 
such file or directory)
07-04 07:56:34.492 1723-1723/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack 
module: -2
07-04 07:56:35.220 1816-1816/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: 
Permission denied (13)
07-04 07:56:37.443 1863-1863/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No 
such file or directory)
07-04 07:56:37.444 1863-1863/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack 
module: -2
07-04 07:56:38.734 1872-1909/com.example.android.camera2basic E/libEGL: 
load_driver(/system/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so): dlopen failed: library 
"/system/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so" not found
07-04 07:56:39.621 1872-1909/com.example.android.camera2basic 
E/EGL_emulation: tid 1909: eglSurfaceAttrib(1174): error 0x3009 
(EGL_BAD_MATCH)
07-04 07:56:40.775 635-727/system_process E/TaskPersister: File error 
accessing recents directory (directory doesn't exist?).
07-04 07:56:44.003 1935-1981/com.android.packageinstaller E/libEGL: 
load_driver(/system/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so): dlopen failed: library 
"/system/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so" not found
07-04 07:56:44.597 1935-1981/com.android.packageinstaller E/EGL_emulation: 
tid 1981: eglSurfaceAttrib(1174): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
```

But when i click on the button **picture** it shows nothing on the logcat. This is the **AndroidManifest.xml** file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.android.camera2basic">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application android:allowBackup="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:theme="@style/MaterialTheme">

    <activity android:name=".CameraActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

i saw many questions with the "Couldn't load memtrack module (No 
such file or directory)" but i couldn't realy relate to them. Can anyone help ? Thank you in advance.

**P.S :** to make the Camera2 API work on emulator is a must for my project that's why i'm asking this. Thank you for understanding

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it in the Android Studio emulator? Does it work there?

This may be a bug specific to the Genymotion emulator, or it could be shared between multiple emulators.